# What does [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ] do in sh?

Tags: shell-script

I found this lovely snippet of code in `/etc/profile` on a CentOS box:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

I know that it loads in the `.sh` files from `/etc/profile.d`, but I'm confounded by the last if statement, `if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]`.  What is this syntax doing?  I'm not even sure where to look it up.

Comment: the `$-`  contains the current shell options.

Comment: Dang, missed that dupe, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, `[ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]` checks whether your shell is interactive.

`$-` contains the flags used for your shell execution (for example: `himBH`, the `i` meaning that the shell is interactive). `${-#*i}` yields the part of `$-` that follows the first `i` (`mBH` with our example). If there is no `i` in `$-` then `${-#*i}` yields `$-`.

That's exactly what the test is about: if the two strings are different, that means that there is a `i` in `$-`, in other words that the shell is interactive.

Comment: It's made more confusing because i is also the loop variable name.  I spent some time trying to see how it worked according to the bash docs, to no avail.  Thanks for the explanation.